# Rails create multiple entries checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I can't find a solution and I'm becoming a little desperate...

form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @skill_user, :url => create_new_skill_users_path do |f| %>

<% @skills.each do |skill| %>
<%= skill.name %>
```

Now...Additional fields...new in

```
<%= f.input :prio, collection: 1..5, :as => :radio_buttons %>
<%= f.text_field :remark%>



<%= check_box_tag "skill_ids[]", "#{skill.id}" %>
<%= hidden_field_tag("skill_id", "#{skill.id}") %>
<%= hidden_field_tag(:user_id, "#{@user.id}") %>
<% end %>
```

controller:

```
def create_new_skill
params[:skill_ids].each do|skill_id|
    SkillUser.create(
         :user_id => user_id, :instruction_id => params[:instruction_id], :remark => ??, :prio => ??
    )
  end
```

Thanks so far for your support.
Now I have a different question/two problems. Would be nice if...you could help me again.

The radio button collection in the form in each line. But not usable because they act as one and not per line. I need some additional parameter to point them to the skill.id of each line.

And also how to fetch the values in the controller.

The remark text field. I get "skill_user"=>{"remark"=>""} in the log. Gets overwritten..needs somewhere a []. What is the best way?

I have tried:

<%= simple_fields_for "skill[]", @skill_user do |f| %>
Gives me Log: 
"skill"=>[{"remark"=>"test"}

controller
:remark => params[:skill][:remark] => can't convert Symbol into Integer
phh...

"text_field_tag[]" gives back a hash..

Answer (score 0):

You should write

```
 params[:skill_ids].each do|skill_id| 
  SkillUser.create(:user_id => params[:user_id], :skill_id => skill_id)
 end
```

in your controller's action.

As well your post action should be on create not on new, as per REST conventions

Comment: remark is inside params skill, because you are overriding form variable f in <%= simple_fields_for "skill[]", @skill_user do **|f|** %> try giving the different name and see how it remark appears in log or rather inspect it with firebug.

Answer (score 0):

As you are probably in the learning phase, I'll recommend you some tips and give you the answer.

Name your actions and controller with a good name. In that case, I guess a SkillController with an action new is a good choice. In routes, use resources instead of match or get/post/put/delete for the most time.

```
 def new_sk
   params[:skill_ids].each do|skill_id| 
    SkillUser.create(
      :user_id => params[:user_id],
      :skill_id => skill_id,
      :name => params[:name]
    )
   end
 end
```

Is the answer. This code is very simple, what you are passing to the SkillUser.create is a HASH with the hash keys being user_id, skill_id and name, and their respective values are params[:user_id], params[:skill_id] and params[:name].

When you don't know the current state of how the "params" variable is(how it's hash values are nested and so on), I advise you to print it, like this:

```
p params.inspect
```

In the beginning of your action, then read what is printed on the terminal you are running your server. There is a gem called `awesome_print` that prints it with colors and is awesome(as the name suggests) when you are just trying to see what is really happening in the server-side.

I also advise you to create a model with a good name. "SkillUser" is wrong, it would be better if you had written UserSkill. You are probably going to work with relations soon and I further advise you to read the Rails guides in that matter.

[Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) are gold. You can find 90% of your questions answered there, with good explanations.

Have a good day.

Comment: Thanks for your support..this works fine now but I have problems with addition fields..text and radio..see above